# Laravel 5.1 | Access denied for database user

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

I'm using the new laravel 5.1 framework with the env file.
So, I've uploaded the framework to **bluehost** server, and for some reason an error came up:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user '**'@'**' (using password: YES)
```

I've got exactly the same credentials on my local server - and it works there, but not on my bluehost server.

Comment: is the database user setup with the correct user and password?  and does that user have access to the correct database?

Comment: As bretterer is implying, this error happens when Laravel is attempting to connect to the database. It looks like you are not specifying a user. Check your database config file and ensure that bluehost is setup with the proper database, user, and user to database assignment.

Comment: I edited my question, I've just found that I was little unclear..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following steps to gain access to MySQL:

1.- Create a database user, execute the following queries:

For a remote user:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_name.* TO 'remoteuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'secret-passwd'
```

For a local user:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_name.* TO 'localuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'secret-passwd'
```

2.- Configure Laravel, edit `config/database.php`:

```
'mysql' => [
    'read' => [
        'host' => 'localhost',
    ],
    'write' => [
        'host' => 'localhost'
    ],
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'database'  => 'db_name',
    'username'  => 'localuser',
    'password'  => 'secret-passwd',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
],
```

For remote connections, change the `localhost` to your server's domain name, eg: `mysql-server.example.net` and your username to `remoteuser` and open port 3306 on your MySQL's server.

Good luck!!

Comment: This is not a good idea.  It leaves things WAY to open.   You should not GRANT ALL on anything that is accessible from any host.

Comment: @bretterer It's more dangerous connecting remotely without TLS. My focus here was giving the op the big picture.

Comment: Well,

It's seems that the problem was in my env file.

In my local server I set the sql server as hostname, but in my web server - I had to set `localhost` as hostname.

Thank you!!